# What are the security implications of sending SAML assertions unsigned?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, xml-signature

I don't have much knowledge about SAML so can someone tell me what is the purpose of signing SAML assertions and what are the security implications of not having them signed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't have a signature in it then you can't verify that the SAML response you receive is actually from the expected sender. It could be from someone else saying "I'm the superadmin and have all permissions, let me in". And you would blindly trust them.

Comment: ah, that makes sense, I was confused because there is one article that says it is not required https://support.pingidentity.com/s/article/Security-implications-for-signing-a-SAML-Response-or-SAML-assertion

"In the case of direct authentication or secure channel establishment (SSL/TLS) its not required that the response/assertion is signed. However, its very common to use the default "sign the response" even if there is a secure ssl channel between IDP and SP."

Maybe I'm misunderstanding this?

Comment: As the article say, the signature is not required when the communication on top of that is already secured and you already know the communication partners. The answer is coming from the connection to that specific host/service (and you verified the SSL connection).

Comment: Signing could be optional if the ARTIFACT binding is used. In this binding the server doesn't return claims but **an artifact**. The SP makes a direct call to the server and exchanges the artifact for a set of claims. Because of this, the server's identity can be validated during this call. A forged response, containing forged artifact, would be rejected by a legit server.

Comment: There's a lot of conflated terms here. You could sign the response but not the assertion within. In that case you can still validate integrity.
You should definitely check the integrity of some part of it either Response or Assertion if you are using Redirect/Post binding, even if using SSL/TLS since the flow is relying on the browser and it can be tampered with.